# How to merge array of strings with an array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, array-merge

The user will put in 3 diff strings in an array. The user will then type in 3 different integers in a diff array. These strings and integers are related. The output will be one single array with these strings and int matched.

For example type in 3 strings:

```
Cat
Dog 
Egg
```

Now type in 3 integers:

```
3
4
5
```

Output is:

```
Cat = 3
Dog = 4
Egg = 5
```

I know how to merge two arrays with just numbers. Just not with two diff arrays with different types.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you need pseudo code? You forgot to mention the language.

Comment: Oh, I am working with Java.

Comment: If the user types them in, why are they not all just strings?

Comment: Even if they are not of the same type initially, they will be printed as strings. Please make an attempt. This is the next tutorial after Hello World

Comment: Just because the numbers look like integers, you can input them as strings.

Comment: Got it! Thanks yall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a case is a good candidate for using `Map` as shown below:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArr = { "Cat", "Dog", "Egg" };
        int[] intArr = { 3, 4, 5 };
        Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(strArr.length, intArr.length); i < n; i++) {
            map.put(strArr[i], intArr[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Cat=3, Dog=4, Egg=5}
```

Alternatively, you can combine each record (the string and its corresponding number) into a string and put it into a `String[]`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strArr = { "Cat", "Dog", "Egg" };
        int[] intArr = { 3, 4, 5 };
        String[] result = new String[strArr.length];
        for (int i = 0, n = Math.min(strArr.length, intArr.length); i < n; i++) {
            result[i] = strArr[i] + " = " + intArr[i];
        }

        // Display
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Cat = 3, Dog = 4, Egg = 5]
```